# read data from an ng-model directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm having some issues in reading data from an ng-model 
parameterized directive. I'm doing like this but it does not work

```
ng-model="NameController.data.sample[{{ name.id_name }}]"

NameController.data = {
  name: ''
}
```

Comment: first, you will need $scope for 2 way binding. and ng-model would be ng-model="NameController.data.name". Please go through https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYssydksrLAhWBMpQKHSNcCq0QFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fthinkster.io%2Fa-better-way-to-learn-angularjs&usg=AFQjCNEPgeimxDF8IY0Nt_nut6w_uHxxEA&bvm=bv.117218890,d.dGo

Answer (score 0):

To acces the ng-model saved data you need to use the `$scope`. To get the info from that `ng-model` you have to use `$scope.NameContro....`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property by dynamic name. For that reason you don't need curly brackets (interpolation) inside Angular expression:

```
ng-model="NameController.data.sample[name.id_name]"
```

Of course, make sure you have `name.id_name` defined on your scope/controller object.